# How to eval import in python?

Tags: python, eval

I get the following error. Is there a way to `eval` `import`?

```
>>> eval('import os')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1
    import os
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Use `importlib` like `os = importlib.import_module('os')`

Comment: Use `exec`, not `eval`.

Comment: The same reason you can't write `x = import os`